# Can I use 'in' instead of 'at'? -- "I have more books in my house."

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am learning English using the *Duolingo* English course, one of correct solution was

> I have more books at my house.

Can I use

> I have more books in my house.

If it is OK, what is the difference between both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a matter of "location" *at my house* vs. "contained/enclosed by/inside" *in my house*.
In your examples, house could refer to a location or what is inside it. Which one is best may depend on context.
For example, when you say:

> I have more books *at* my house.

they could be on the driveway, in your backyard, etc. as these would still be referred to as your house location-wise.

When you say:

> I have more books *in* my house.

they could be in a desk drawer, in your room, etc. stating what they are inside of.

You could say:

> I have more books in my desk drawer.

but you would not say:

> I have more books at my desk drawer.

But if you are specific about location:

> I have more friends *at* the lake.

this probably does not mean the same thing as:

> I have more friends *in* the lake.